# Using Match to find multiple rows with data

Tags: r, match

So I am trying to use the match function to find empty cells in the first column of my table. Here is what I've used so far.

```
rowNo <- list(match("", table[,1]))
```

and this

```
rowNo <- list(match("", table[1:nrow(table),1]))
```

I've also tried not using the list function on them.

What I want is a list of row numbers, but it keeps giving me just one row number when I want it to give me EVERY row number for blank cell in the first column.

Hopefully this is clear enough. If you have any questions leave a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a search on a random dead forum I found the answer to my own question.

```
rowNo <- which(table[,1]=="")
```

works a lot better than match for this :-)